# Rails: working with associations and join-table in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, associations, join

I have a **User** model and a **Product** model with a many-to-many association and in both models I have "has_and_belongs_to_many"

I understand that this allows me to work with relations like this:

```
user = User.first

user.products #shows all products bought by a user
```

and

```
product = Product.first

product.users # show all users who bought that product
```

But there might be a product which has not been bought by any user yet, so this product will be in *products* table but not in the *user_products* join-table.

**How do I return only user-products associations which have been saved in the join table?**

Also, say I want to create a product and at the same time define that it has been bought by - belongs to - first and second user. I thought of:

```
User.all[0..1].each {|usr| usr.product.create(name: "tv")}
```

**Is this the correct way to imply an association and populate the join-table with a record for it?**

What if, as I said above, I have a product that is in *products* table but still no User had bought it, and now a user buys it: **how can I express this so that later I can do**

```
user.products
```

**and see that product**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return only user-products associations which have been saved in the join table?

You can't, because you've decided to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` where the join table is not accessible at all. Consider using `has_many through` relation.

> Is this the correct way to imply an association and populate the join-table with a record for it?

It should be:

```
User.limit(2).each {|usr| usr.products.create(name: "tv")}
```

or

```
User.limit(2).each {|usr| usr.products << Product.create(name: "tv")}
```

> What if, as I said above, I have a product that is in products table but still no User had bought it, and now a user buys it: how can I express this so that later I can do

Simply `user.products.reload`

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful! But in last question I actually meant: how do I actually add a new product to an old user ?
Also I've just discovered this: `User.joins(:products)`. Doesn't this do what I asked in first question?

Comment: If you want to add new product to an existing user, simply put `User.last.products.create(name: "tv")`, however if you want to join an exiting user with existing product, then it would be: `User.last.products << Product.last`. For `has_many` relationship, that would be helpful for you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many . Clarifying the first question, perhaps I misunderstood your purpose, `User.joins(:products)` gives you users having products. I thought you want to access the join table, i.e. `User.last.product_users`

Comment: Thanks! All parts covered now :) Will try to ask a last one here :) -> Do you think that with the current data modeling setup I can enforce uniqueness in the records of join-table? I see I can join a user to a product multiple times, which is not what I want....

Comment: You need to add a uniqueness constraint to your association. It might be on application level or database level. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992618/2458753

Comment: Thanks, the link you adviced was perfect: as explained there I added an index for the join table composed of product_id and user_id. Works great.. now onto db exception handling.. :)

Comment: `User.first(2).each {...}` is nice too.