# Invalid DB operation going to DB constraint _before_ data model validation? (HABTM uniqueness)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, rspec-rails

I have a model (`Company`) with a HABTM self-join relationship (the join table calls associated companies `suppliers` and `purchasers`).

I want to prevent companies from ever having duplicate suppliers or purchasers, so I'm adding a uniqueness constraint on supplier-purchaser pairs. I'm adding this constraint at both the database level:

```
create_table :supply_link, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :supplier,  null: false, index: true
  t.belongs_to :purchaser, null: false, index: true
end

add_index :supply_link, [:supplier_id, :purchaser_id], unique: true
```

and the data model level:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :purchasers, -> { distinct },
                                       join_table: :supply_link,
                                       class_name: :Company,
                                       foreign_key: :supplier_id,
                                       association_foreign_key: :purchaser_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers, -> { distinct },
                                      join_table: :supply_link,
                                      class_name: :Company,
                                      foreign_key: :purchaser_id,
                                      association_foreign_key: :supplier_id

end
```

But in trying to write a spec for this arrangement, I noticed something strange: *typically, data model validations preempt database constraints — but not here.*

That is, if you set both a data model validation (`validates :email, presence: true`) and a DB constraint (`t.string :email, null: false`), then the data model catches invalid operations (like `User.create(email: nil)`) before the DB ever even sees them.

But in this case, when I try to add the same `supplier` to a `Company` multiple times, it goes to the *database* first, and raises an error. If I remove the database constraint altogether, then <s>the data model handles it the right way, and the duplicate entries never get added to the `suppliers` attribute.</s> two things happen: 1) the duplicate associations all appear in the join table, but 2) the model doesn't show any duplicates for `company.suppliers` (thanks @Pavel Mihailyuk). I've tested this manually in the console, and with RSpec/FactoryGirl.

What's going on here, and what's the right way to write the specs? Should I keep both validations and expect invalid operations to raise an `ActiveRecord` error? Should I remove the database constraint and rely solely on the data model's `-> { distinct }` scope? Should I report this as a bug in Rails?

Comment: "...and the duplicate entries never get added to the `suppliers` attribute" - it it is not a fact. You have to test it in db console not in Rails one due to `-> { distinct }`. Golden rule: only DB constraints will save your data :)

Comment: You again! You're absolutely right; thanks, I knew I forgot to check somewhere.

Comment: Never trust Rails or any part of it :) Build your app around DB, add DB constraints/indexes as many as required by business logic. Always check what exactly query AR have built, what exactly DB state is after migration (example `\d tablename` in psql). That is only way to have live production app :)

Comment: Ok, so this still begs the question: how should one write specs to ensure that the DB constraints work in cases where invalid data is normally caught by the data model? You can't expect an `ActiveRecord` error when the data model doesn't try to save invalid input...

Comment: You can search for "HABTM uniq". There are many answers on SO. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896450/habtm-duplicate-records

Comment: As for test, you have to decide what the app flow in case of duplicate insert attempt. I.e. who should catch exception. Then you can build test on top of it