# Database uniqueness constraint not stopping duplicate record creation through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am attempting to add a uniqueness constraint to my database to stop duplicate entries being added to a join table. However, it does not seem to be working. I do not have a model for the join table, so I am not adding model level validations.

Here is the migration:

```
class CreateBreedsAndTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :breeds do |t|
      t.string :name, unique: true, present: true
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name, unique: true, present: true
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_join_table :breeds, :tags do |t|
      t.integer :breed_id
      t.integer :tag_id
      t.index [:breed_id, :tag_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

The Breed and Tag models are both very simple, and they use `has_and_belongs_to_many` because I wanted to test out the association. I could add add `-> { distinct }` to the association, but I would like to stop duplicates from being created in the first place.

```
class Breed < ApplicationRecord
  # Some validations and stuff here
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

If I create a Breed and Tag in the rails console. I can do something like this even though there is a database level unique constraint on the join table:

```
b = Breed.create(name: 'b')
t = Tag.create(name: 't')
b << t
b << t
b.save!
b.tags # outputs the same tag multiple times
```

EDIT:

1) It's worth noting that I found this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315109/rails-idiom-to-avoid-duplicates-in-has-many-through) which recommends overriting the `<<` in the association. However, this doesn't explain why my unique constraint is failing.

2) I also found this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896450/habtm-duplicate-records) which recommends a db level constraint, but that is not working for me.

EDIT2:

Here is some table information from the database:

```
       table_name        |               index_name                |   column_name   
-------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------
 ar_internal_metadata    | ar_internal_metadata_pkey               | key
 breed_tags              | breed_tags_pkey                         | id
 breeds                  | breeds_pkey                             | id
 breeds_tags             | index_breeds_tags_on_breed_id           | breed_id
 breeds_tags             | index_breeds_tags_on_tag_id             | tag_id
```

And I ran a `\d breeds_tags`

```
  Table "public.breeds_tags"
  Column  |  Type  | Modifiers 
----------+--------+-----------
 breed_id | bigint | not null
 tag_id   | bigint | not null
Indexes:
    "index_breeds_tags_on_breed_id" btree (breed_id)
    "index_breeds_tags_on_tag_id" btree (tag_id)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the join table in the database through `psql` (i.e. without all the ActiveRecord stuff in the way)?

Comment: @muistooshort I updated my answer with some database information. It looks like it created two indexes, but I don't see a unique constraint? There is als oa `breed_tags` table! I basically ran the query from this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204058/list-columns-with-indexes-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Dbz: You're right. Rails created two indexes; it created no unique constraint. [Rails's `uniqueness` helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) "validates that the attribute's value is unique right before the object gets saved. It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database . . . "

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I'm not actually using the uniqueness helper, but  a database constraint. I'll create a join model so that I can also have a uniqueness helper. However, I think it is odd that this db constraint is not working.

Comment: You do *not* have the database constraint you think you have.

Comment: Yes, I know. It also wasn't showing up on the schema. However, I don't know why

Comment: Because you didn't use `add_index`.

Comment: With your table and column names, psql would show a unique index something like this: `"breed_tags_breed_id_tag_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (breed_id, tag_id)`.

Answer (score 2):

Each migration should at most create or alter a single table. Each migration should be an atomical and reverseable change to the db. If you create both the tables and a foreign key that references the same in the same migration what would happen if you try to reverse it?

```
# rails g model tags name:string
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# rails g model breeds name:string
class CreateBreeds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :breeds do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# rails g migration create_join_table_breeds_tags breeds tags
class CreateJoinTableBreedsTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :breeds, :tags do |t|
      t.index [:breed_id, :tag_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Also the `create_join_table` macro creates the foreign key columns. So you don't need to manually add them:

```
# don't do this.
t.integer :breed_id
t.integer :tag_id
```

In fact you should almost never use `t.integer` for associations. Use the references macro instead.

This creates a uniqueness constraint that works as expected:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 1, name: "bar", created_at: "2017-11-03 23:34:51", updated_at: "2017-11-03 23:34:51">]>
irb(main):005:0> b.tags << t
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.8ms)  INSERT INTO "breeds_tags" ("breed_id", "tag_id") VALUES ($1, $2)  [["breed_id", 1], ["tag_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_breeds_tags_on_breed_id_and_tag_id"
DETAIL:  Key (breed_id, tag_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

However if you need the join to be unique you should use `has_many through:` and create a model as `has_and_belongs_to` does not provide a way for the app to check uniqueness before the database driver blows up. It would require you to wrap your code in some really dirty rescue statements to catch the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception.

This is not a good idea since [exceptions should not be used for normal flow  control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).

```
# rails g model breed_tag breed:belongs_to 

# the table naming for has_many through: is different
class CreateBreedTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :breed_tags do |t|
      t.belongs_to :breed, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :tag, foreign_key: true
      t.index [:breed_id, :tag_id], unique: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class BreedTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :breed
  belongs_to :tag
  validates_uniqueness_of :breed_id, scope: :tag_id
end

class Breed < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :breed_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :breed_tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :breed_tags
  has_many :breeds, through: :breed_tags
end
```

Comment: This does not answer exactly why your code creates two indexes. But I could not replicate the issue and this is tested to actually work in a Rails 5 app.

Comment: Hey max, thank you for the answer. I agree about using `references` (and there is no need for a join table), but I was frantically testing anything! I'll give your suggestions some thoughts and test. Thank you again